# Сортировка массива объектов, по определенному полю

Tags: c#

Как верно реализовать метод CompareTo для сортировки массива объектов по определенному полю объектов. Вот то, что у меня дано и набросал:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public abstract class Software
{
    public string name_soft;
    public string made;

    public virtual void Information()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.name_soft+" "+this.made);
    }
    public virtual bool can=> true;
}
public class FreeSoftware : Software
{
    public FreeSoftware(string name, string made)
    {
        base.name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
    }
}
public class SharewareSoftware : Software
{
    private DateTime date_instal;
    private DateTime period_free;
    public SharewareSoftware(string name, string made, DateTime date_instal, DateTime period)
    {
        base.name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
        this.date_instal = date_instal;
        period_free = period;
    }
    public override void Information()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name_soft+" "+made+" "+date_instal.ToString("d")+" "+period_free.ToString("d"));
    }
    public override bool can=> (new DateTime(date_instal.Year - period_free.Year, date_instal.Month - period_free.Month, date_instal.Day - period_free.Day))<= DateTime.Now;

}
public class ProprietarySoftware : Software {
    private DateTime date_instal;
    private DateTime time_use;
    private double price;
    public ProprietarySoftware(string name,string made,DateTime date_instal,DateTime time_use,double price)
    {
        name_soft = name;
        base.made = made;
        this.date_instal = date_instal;
        this.time_use = time_use;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public override void Information()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name_soft+" "+made+" "+ price+" "+date_instal.ToString("d")+" "+time_use.ToString("d"));
    }
    public override bool can=> (new DateTime(date_instal.Year - time_use.Year, date_instal.Month - time_use.Month, date_instal.Day - time_use.Day)) == DateTime.Now;

}
```

Я не понимаю как мне создать массив из различных объектов и по поводу реализации метода сортировки... Может я очень тупой, но я просто не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = new List<Software>();

list.Add(new FreeSoftware("FreeSoftware", "Inc"));
list.Add(new SharewareSoftware ("SharewareSoftware ", "Anc"));

foreach(var software in list.OrderBy(s=>s.name_soft).ThenBy(s=>s.made))
     Console.WriteLine($"{software.made} - {software.name_soft}");
```

Comment: Эм, так я понял, что нужно использовать всё же список. Спасибо за помощь. 
отлично) А случайно сортировка не через linq производится?

Comment: @Valera да, я в ответе использовал Linq для сортировки. Этот же код будет работать и для массивов, если вам нужны массивы

Comment: проблема в том, что я не представляю, как реализовать массив, если с списком всё ясно, указываешь что список будет состоять из объектов и нет проблем, если я пытаюсь сделать примерно тоже с массивом, допустим: Software[] soft=new Software[5];
И дальше пытаюсь забросить объект другого класса, то ошибка

Comment: @Valera `пытаюсь забросить объект другого класса` как именно? Добавьте ваш код в ваш вопрос

Comment: прошу прощения за свою глупость. Всё добавляется.
А в чём будет разница между реализацией CompareTo сортировки и linq?

Comment: @Valera в том, что вы не запачкаете свои классы лишней ерундой типа способа их сортировки в каком то там участке кода

Comment: если я правильно понял, то нужно будет реализовывать отдельный класс наследующий интерфейс IComparer, там описывать метод CompareTo, и только потом я смогу нормально отсортировать?

Comment: @Valera либо писать да, [IComparer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=netframework-4.7.2), либо свои классы заставлять реализовывать [IComparable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2), либо писать как я показал. Что выбрать? Задймайтесь, есть ли у вас хотя бы одна причина писать классы отдельные или пачкать свои классы лишней функциональностью? Если есть - то дерзайте, если нет - то OrderBy ваш друг.

Comment: Спасибо большое)!